# Xcode: linker complains about missing symbols for tests, but not for run

Tags: ios, xcode, linker, lldb

In an iOS project, I'm using a library provided by third-party vendor. Well, partly provided actually, since a part of it was under GPL license.

The other part, I had to reimplement. That's done, and it compiles, runs and archives properly on a device.

But then I try to run the unit tests (or run on simulator), and stuff goes wrong. The linker complains about missing symbols. Two functions, defined as

```
extern int my_function();

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_my_function", referenced from:
```

And indeed, they are missing! The two functions are not defined anywhere in my code.

But still, I can compile, link and run normally. After a bit of research, I figured out that the code referencing these functions may have been stripped somehow by the compiler, since it's a path that is never taken (and that can be determined at compile time).

My first reaction was to check optimization, but it's set to `-O0` for every run I made.

I should probably fix that and define these functions anyway, but I'm curious. What makes the linker complain in the test/simulator build and not the run on device?

Comment: Do you by any chance have to include external libraries that the third party library depend upon?

Comment: Nope, everything is supposed to be in the sources. But then again, these two functions are definitely missing.